# How to parse Optional Json to String variables

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to get data from my database using Firebase. I am unsure how to unwrap and assign the variables. I am trying to have a title on the top of the screen based on the name imported, likes, and playing the video.

When I print the variable jdata it prints the Optional JSON from the firebase.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import AVKit
import Firebase


struct PlayerView: View {
    
    @State var likes: Int = 0
    @State var name: String = ""
    @State var url: String = ""
    @State let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: url))
    
    func liked() { likes += 1 }
    func update() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        let root = Database.database().reference()
        root.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let data = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                let jdata = data["urls"] // Optional JSON
                print(jdata)
            }
        })
            
        
    }

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            Text(name)
            VideoPlayer(player: player).padding()
        
            HStack {
                Button("Like", action: liked).padding()
                Text(String(likes)).padding()
            }
            HStack {
                Button("Prev"){}.padding()
                Button("Next"){}.padding()
            }
            Button(action: update) {
                Text("Update Database")
                
            }.padding()

        }
    }
}
```

My variable after it prints
Optional({"-N25GwfJ9Cj7IlfkFNpL" = { likes = 0; name = "NameTest"; url = "Testing"; }; })

Comment: are you going to do your old trick, get the answer to the question, then delete the question, like you did last time?

Comment: Since you haven't included your schema, it's tough to say exactly how to parse it. If `"urls"` contains a *single* `String`, you could do `if let jdata = data["urls"] as? String { self.url = jdata }`. If it contains multiple URLs, as the name implies, you'd have to decide which item you want.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Hi again! I deleted the question because I received negative reviews on it. I assumed this platform is like Reddit and I did not want to have a bad question as the negative review was indicating. I thought I might have made a mistake posting the question since it was moved past the original question. Leading to making it harder to read for other people. That is why I deleted the previous question. Your help has been unbelievable, especially with understanding the language itself. Regardless, thank you for your time.

Comment: @jnpdx My JSON when I print it looks like this.     Optional({"-N25GwfJ9Cj7IlfkFNpL" =     {
        likes = 0;
        name = "Name ";
        url = "Jaded;kjashdfkljhwe;ifugweiufhwie";
    };
})

I have tried using the data["urls"]["name"] syntax but this was not working for me.

Comment: Looks like you have a document keyed by id. You need to get the document out first, then query the properties on it.

Comment: I was surprised to see your previous question deleted, since you seemed to be happy with the answers/comments I provided.
So I wondered what happened. You reply to my (somewhat terse comment) is appreciated.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I usually am the fastest to reply to everything in my personal life haha. However, I did not want you to get the wrong idea. I was very happy with your answer and comments. You followed the problem all the way through. I just felt bad since the question had a -2 reputation. I thought this might have been a bad question. Nonetheless, I really am grateful for your help.

Comment: @jnpdx How would I be able to do this process? Sorry, I am still confused since I thought I could just remove the optional and then just access the data.

Comment: Maybe you only have (and will only ever have?) one child/root entry, but generally you want to query for that first. Check out the documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write) which will show you how to read/write specific children in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the data you show, you could try this (untested) approach:

```
root.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    if let data = snapshot.value as? [String: Any],
        let jdata = data["urls"] as? [String: Any] {
        if let key = jdata.keys.first,
           let result = jdata[key] as? [String: Any] {
            print("-----> result: \(result)")
            if let likes = result["likes"] {
                print("-----> likes: \(likes)")
            }
        }
    }
  })
```